# How to compare values in Excel file before uploading?

Tags: apex, code, collection

Inserting excel file using apex, I have 4 columns in file,Column-1 (Name) can contain duplicate values. I want to perform check if column-1 has same values (for example A) and column-2(codes) has different values for that particular **A-Name** want to give error saying that the codes are different for same name.

My approaching is added column1 to the list1 and column4 to the list2  but it doesn't seem to work.

If anyone know the logic kindly help me with this ?

Part of code :

```
     List<customObject> newList = new List<customObject>();
        String[] errors = new List<String>();
        map<String,String> nameToCode = new map<String,String>();
        for (Integer i=1;i<lines.size();i++){
           String[] valuesFromFile = new String[]{};
           valuesFromFile = lines[i].split(',');

           customObject co = new customObject();
           co.Name__c = valuesFromFile[0];
           co.City__c = valuesFromFile[1];
           co.State__c = valuesFromFile[2];
           co.Code__c = valuesFromFile[3];
           newList.add(co);

            if (nameToCode.containsKey(co.Name__c) {
              if (nameToCode.get(co.Name__c) != co.Code__c)
                 ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Please check code for Name:' + co.Name__c));
}
 else nameToCode.put(co.Name__c,co.Code__c);


            }
         }
         insert newList;
```

Comment: Can you add a helper column? Concatenate `Name__c` and `Code__c` then you will can compare them together in a single check.

Comment: @jatuttle0  Thanks for your response this file will be uploaded by some other users and they cannot concatenate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a map of `nameToCode` as in:

```
String[] errors = new List<String>();
map<String,String> nameToCode = new map<String,String>();
for (Integer i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {

   ... parse and add to customObject

   if (nameToCode.containsKey(co.Name__c) {
      if (nameToCode.get(co.Name__c) != co.Code__c)
         errors.add('Row ' + i + ' has different code for Name: ' + co.Name__c + ' as entered elsewhere in CSV.');
      else {}  // benign
   else 
      nameToCode.put(co.Name__c,co.Code__c);
}
```

Some things to think about:

1. Your CSV line parser will break if there are commas embedded in a cell's value.
2. The map solution above is case sensitive. Adjust accordingly to be case insensitive if that is a requirement.

Comment: thanks fro your response sorry if you misunderstood my question. Codes are like (1,2,3,4) and Names will be like {A,B,C,D} I want to ensure Name A -> has code 1(in file) then all the codes for Name A should be 1 if not give error

Comment: @SFDC - that is what the code does, it tracks in a map all Names and the first code for that Name encountered, then the next time the same name is found in the file, it compares the current code to the saved (first-encountered) code

Comment: I added the logic you provided, it is showing error for all the records even if they have same codes :(

Comment: @SFDC - use the Edit link and amend your OP to reflect current code

Comment: edited the code & added nameToCode.put(co.Name__c,co.Code__c); first ,if not it will be always false and allowing all records

Comment: @SFDC - I indented your code to make it readable; you can't unconditionally put into the map as it will smash the previous value for the same `Name__c`